# Running pulseaudio in a headless server installation

Tags: vlc-media-player, pulse-audio, ubuntu-18.04, headless

I'm trying to play some music on my headless linux installation. At first, I thought, there should be any problem, you have to connect to the server over ssh and run some commands like cvlc a_random_music_file.mp3 ... But...no!

```
user@server:~$cvlc -I http --http-password password a_random_music_file.mp3
VLC media player 3.0.4 Vetinari (revision 3.0.4-0-gf615db6332)
[000055e4d5da6ee0] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[000055e4d5cc1570] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" 
initialization failed
[000055e4d5da6ee0] [http] lua interface: Lua HTTP interface
[00007fc598c05770] prefetch stream error: unimplemented query (264) in control
```

And i'm gettting no sound, do you have any ideas? P.S. The speakers are connected to the server.

Comment: Have you checked whether the pulseaudio session-service is running and whether it reports any audio outputs (sinks)?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/145135/set-default-sound-device-output , Also, sometimes settings seem not to take until PulseAudio is restarted.

Comment: Thanks you, it works! Setting the default device output helped, Additionally, I ran pulseaudio as a system-wide instance